# Changing value of variable in android /JAVA

Tags: java, android, button, textview, onclicklistener

I was trying to make a simple app in which clicking `tapb Button` increments the variable value of notaps and the reset `Button` sets it to 0. When I click on `tapb` it increments the value & clicking `reset` resets it but when I again click `tabp` it increments from the previous value.

Eg :

```
init value of notaps = 0;
```

I click `tabp` 3 times and `notaps` value = 3

I click `reset` and  `notaps` value = 0

I click `tabp` 3 times and `notaps` value = 4

```
    Button tapb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tapb);
    Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);


    tapb.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                int notaps = 0;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView taps = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.taps);
                    notaps++;
                    taps.setText(String.valueOf(notaps));

                }
            }
    );

    reset.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView taps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taps);
                    int notaps=0;
                    taps.setText(String.valueOf(notaps));

                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: declare notaps globally...

Comment: int noTaps=0 is bad. That variable disappears after that method executes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have 2 instances of `int` named `notaps` that have nothing to do with each other. Your reset button does not set the right `notaps` variable.

Here's a snippet that should work.

```
    private int notaps;

    Button tapb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tapb);
    Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    TextView taps = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.taps);

    tapb.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notaps++;
                taps.setText(String.valueOf(notaps));
            }
        }
    );

    reset.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notaps = 0;
                taps.setText(String.valueOf(notaps));
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: I did a stupid mistake i declared int notaps in side onCreate

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring your notaps variable globally meaning where every you declare you buttons declare your notaps variable there, here is what I mean.

```
Button tapb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tapb);
Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
int notaps = 0; // declare variable globally

tapb.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView taps = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.taps);
                taps.setText(String.valueOf(++notaps));

            }
        }
);

reset.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView taps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taps);                    
                taps.setText(String.valueOf(notaps=0));

            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Don't declare it volatile. You're not going to access the variable from multiple threads, only the UI thread.

Comment: I'm not the best in android, but i thought that the listeners were callbacks from another thread. So therefore I declared the variable volatile, my bad if i was wrong.

Comment: The callbacks are called on the UI thread, by the buttons. Every UI interaction happens on the UI thread ("main" thread).

Comment: All I can say is this: keep up the good work and continue experimenting and learning! ;)

Comment: so if i have to access a variable from another thread i need to declare it volatile
**note for future

Comment: Yes absolutely, however ultimately it depends the actual machine, if the machine architecture is such that when a thread is created it is give it's own cache, then volatile saves the day because, what volatile does is it allows a shared copy of the variable you are accessing, but again some machine architectures don't have this problem volatile is there for the sake of portability.